# grep a string from a specific block of text

Tags: bash, awk, grep

Some help required please...
I have a block of text in a file on my Linux machine like this;

```
Block.1:\
 :Value1=something:\
 :Value2=something_else:\
 :Value3=something_other:
Block.2:\
 :Value1=something:\
 :Value2=something_else:\
 :Value3=something_other:
Block.n:\
 :Value1=something:\
 :Value2=something_else:\
 :Value3=something_other:
```

How can I use grep (and/or possibly awk?) to pluck out e.g Value2 from Block.2 only?
Blocks won't always be ordered sequentially (they have arbitary names) but will always be unique.
Colon and backslash positions are absolute.
TIA, Rob.

Comment: So you want to get only value2's value or all value2s in all blocks? please confirm once?

Comment: Just the value2 from Block.2. "value2" will be present in other blocks but are not required. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Following `awk` may help you in same.

```
awk -F"=" '/^Block\.2/{flag=1} flag && /Value2/{print $2;flag=""}'  Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
something_else:\
```

In case you want to print full line of `value2` in block2 then change from `print $2` to `print` in above code.

***Explanation:*** Adding explanation of above code too now.

```
awk -F"=" '         ##Creating field separator as = for each line of Input_file.
/Block\.2/{         ##Checking condition if a line is having string Block.2, here I have escaped . to refrain its special meaning, if condition is TRUE then do follow:
  flag=1            ##Setting variable flag value as 1, which indicates that flag is TRUE.
}
flag && /Value2/{   ##Checking condition if flag value is TRUE and line is having string Value2 in it then do following:
  print $2;         ##Printing 2nd field of the current line.
  flag=""           ##Nullifying the variable flag now.
}
'  Input_file       ##Mentioning the Input_file name here.
```

Comment: `/^Block\.2/` to be even more precise.

Comment: This is awesome.  Works a treat. Thanks very much!

Comment: @Rob Don't assume that a script that produces the expected output given some specific input is correct. That's just the starting point for identifying a working script, you need to **think** about what it's doing. Try it when Value2 is not present in Block.2 but is present in Block.3. Try it when Value2 is not present in Block.2 but Value 21 is present instead. Try it when Block.2 is not present but Block.21 is. Etc, etc.. You can help yourself by coming up with sample input/output that better tests a potential solution against common logic errors like that.

Comment: Cheers @Ed. Fully take your point on board. In my particular use case - there's some pre-checks to determine the 'format-type'. Particular format types dictate the inclusion or exclusion of 'Value's - just not necessarily the order.  Long story short - while I agree with you - many trip-up scenarios are already discounted.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS="[:=]" }
NF==2 { f = ($1 == "Block.2" ? 1 : 0) }
f && ($2 == "Value2") { print $3 }

$ awk -f tst.awk file
something_else
```

Comment: I like this too.  Similar solution to Rav's I suppose.
Could you explain what this is doing though:    ? 1 : 0

Comment: Similar approach but without the potential failure cases. It's a ternary expression (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:) that sets f to 0 or 1 at the start of each Block so f is only set to 1 in **the** specific block you care about, it doesnt continue to be set for subsequent blocks if Value2 doesn't exist in Block.2.

Answer (score 0):

```
grep -A 2 "Block.2" | tail -1 | cut -d= -f2
```

explanation :

- grep -A look for a pattern and prints 2 more lines (till Value2)
- tail -1 gets the last line (the one with Value2)
- cut use "=" as a field separator and prints second field

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately -A isn't available to my version of grep.